# execute code after event handler

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have a problem with my code in a Xamarin portable project. My boolean flag is executed before event handler method but I don't want this.

static **Client.cs** (class which should only connect with web service)

```
public static bool IsConnected;
private static string _username;
private static string _password;
private static void Login()
{
        // all login procedures
        Connection.ServiceUserAuthorisationCompleted +=      UserAuthorisationCompleted;
        Connection.ServiceUserAuthorisationAsync(_login, _password);
}
 private static void UserAuthorisationCompleted(object sender, ServiceUserAuthorisationCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            IsConnected = e.Result.status.Equals("1");
        }
public static Task LoginAsync(string username, string password)
        {
            _username = username;
            _password = password;

            var task = new Task(Login);
            task.Start();

            return task;
        }
```

and my login page in app:

```
private async void SignInClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var login = Login.Text;
            var password = Password.Text;

            await Client.LoginAsync(login, password);
            if (Client.IsConnected)
            {
                MyCredentials.SaveCredentials(login, password);
            }
        }
```

flag `IsConnected` in `Client` class isn't initialized before my `if` statement, so the event handler executes always after where i want.

Comment: You need to build a bridge between Event-based Async Pattern and Taskbased Async Pattern here. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/interop-with-other-asynchronous-patterns-and-types#EAP

Comment: thanks @Fildor
your reply was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

You should await the authorization call, this way the method calling LoginAsync will go further after your authorization happens and IsConnected should be updated by then.

```
public static async Task LoginAsync(string username, string password)
{
    _username = username;
    _password = password;

    Connection.ServiceUserAuthorisationCompleted += UserAuthorisationCompleted;
    await Connection.ServiceUserAuthorisationAsync(_login, _password);
}
```

Comment: That's probably not enough since the flag is set in the EventHandler. There need to be a "bridge" between EAP and TAP.

Comment: yes, flag is set in event handler. however, i cant await the authorization call because it return void

Comment: Yes, you can - in a way. With TaskCompletionSource.